# Is it bad practice to let Node.js talk to a REPL child process?

Tags: c#, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I have a Node.js process that spawns a child REPL process. This child process speaks C# and is able to load DLL files dynamically. I send input to the REPL using either methods or sometimes using a Proxy(). The stdout of the REPL is sent back to my object and then caught using a common obj.on(data, function) implementation. When I invoke a method on the object, it will pass it to the child process stdin.

This all works like a charm, I can load any .NET or third party assembly and expose its types and methods to Node. Although extremely effective, it just instinctively feels very ugly do to it this way.

It does not have to work other platforms besides Windows.

**Is this 'bad practice'? If so, why is this so? What is bad about it? How would you do it better?**

edit: I am not looking for an alternative way, but I would like an answer to my questions that I now made bold.

Answer (score 0):

If you need interop between node and .NET in either direction, there is the [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) project, which may be the kind of thing you're looking for. Currently accessing CLR from node is available cross-platform (Windows, Linux, OS X).

Comment: Thanks but this is not an answer to my question. My solution is better (for me) than Edge.  The question is whether it is  bad practice to let Node talk to any type of REPL.

Comment: I recommended it because it is a "better practice" to interact with it directly than to use a middleman (e.g. a REPL), if for no other reason than performance.